# Detect walking on floor - works partially

Tags: unity, collision-detection

I have a set of Gameobject blocks that form a floor with Box Collider and a GameObject with a Box Collider in it.

My first hunch detecting hitting the floor was:

```
void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision) {
    print ("Enter: " + collision.gameObject.tag);
    switch (collision.gameObject.tag) {
        case "Floor":
            isOnFloor = true;
            break;
    }
}
```

This works well. However, when I want to check whether he left the floor (falling):

```
void OnCollisionExit2D(Collision2D collision) {
    print ("Exit: " + collision.gameObject.tag);
    switch (collision.gameObject.tag) {
        case "Floor":
            isOnFloor = false;
            break;
    }
}
```

The GameObject Drops down as soon as I move a little, as I get the OnCollisionExit2D method...

How do I create a constant movement on a floor, and invoke "falling" only if I completely leave it?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post screenshot of your character with Colliders visible?

Comment: I think what might be happening is as soon as you move you may be stepping on another block which means you exit it's collision so isOnFloor is set to false.

Answer (score 2):

Just like Vadim Tatarnikov said the reason why you fall is because your isOnFloor bool is set to false when you walk over to another block. to prevent all of this I would suggest going with the raycast way instead of box collisions. So to check if your GameObject is on the floor the best thing would be to cast a ray underneath this GameObject and see if there is a floor beneath it. This way you could also detect if your player is jumping by checking how long the Raycast is from your GameObject to the ground.

```
    float rayDistance = 100;
    RaycastHit hit;
    if (Physics.Raycast(transform.position, -transform.up, out hit, rayDistance))
    {
        //Hit is detected, you can now check with the RaycastHit how far away and what object you hit and apply logic there.
        Debug.Log("Raycast hit object " + hit.transform.name);
        Debug.Log("Distance between object and " + hit.transform.name + ": " + hit.distance);

        //You can even debug the line so you can see it in the scene
        Debug.DrawLine(transform.position, hit.point, Color.blue, 10);
    }
```

You should place this code in your update method for precise checking.

Here is the documentation of the Raycast https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.Raycast.html

Answer (score 0):

if you set the floor blocks to a new layer (ex. "Floor") you can detect it using `Physics2D.OverlapCircle()`

```
private bool isGrounded = false;
[SerializeField]
private LayerMask groundLayer;//set this to the Floor layer in the inspector
```

make a private bool isGrounded variable and in FixedUpdate() you can have it detecting the ground. Physics2D.OverlapCircle() can also be useful for detecting many layers such as ceilings, ropes, ice, ladders ect.

```
isGrounded = Physics2D.OverlapCircle(groundCheck.position, groundedRadius, groundLayer);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you insist on using OnCollisionEnter and OnCollisionExit to detect if you are stepping on something, I'd suggest doing the following:

- Create a new variable of type `int`. Let's call it `StepOnCount`, init it to 0.
- Change the `OnCollisionEnter` to:

  ```
  void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision) {
      print ("Enter: " + collision.gameObject.tag);
      switch (collision.gameObject.tag) {
          case "Floor":
              StepOnCount++;
              isOnFloor = true;
              break;
      }
   }
  ```
- Change the `OnCollisionExit` to:

  ```
  void OnCollisionExit2D(Collision2D collision) {
      print ("Exit: " + collision.gameObject.tag);
      switch (collision.gameObject.tag) {
          case "Floor":
          StepOnCount--; 
          if(StepOnCount == 0)
              isOnFloor = false;
          break;
      }
  }
  ```

This way you keep track on how many blocks you are stepping on: **You don't want to fall when you stop steping a block, you want to fall when you are stepping on no block.**

PD: If you are working on a 2D platformer, the other answers given here are a better approach. If you are working on a top-down or 3 fourths perspective game, I'd suggest using my solution.